# How to store value into a nested array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist, react-native

I just want to store a nested array data into a single variable.

I have this code:

```
 var indents = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.state.box; i++){
        indents.push(<Input fluid label={i} placeholder='Item Description..' style={{padding: 5}} />);
    }

<Input label={{ basic: true, content: 'box' }}
                labelPosition='right'
                placeholder='Enter Quantity...'
                size = 'small'
                value={this.state.box}
                onChange={this.handlebox}
                />
```

This means that if I input a number of the box, another field will show the same number of field that I input. But the problem is I can't get the value of all items.

```
Example: if I input to a box field with 5,
         another 5 fields show, name items
```

How can I get the value like this:

```
Values = [valueOf_field1, valueOf_field2, valueOf_field3, valueOf_field4, valueOf_field5];
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. So you have these `Input` components, and when you put, say, 5 into the component's box, you want 5 of that Input component's field values displayed in another component? Also, what specific issues/errors are you facing, when you try to do it what specifically happens? Any console errors?

Comment: I have an 'INPUTFIELD' name box if I input any number of that field, let's say 5, There's another 'INPUTFIELD' that show name items. Note: 5 INPUTFIELD(items) will show because I input 5 into the INPUTFIELD(box). Now my question is how can I store the 5 values of the INPUTFIELD(items) to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `refs` to achieve this. If you want validations and stuffs, i suggest `formsy` can do a better job. But this way is a simple way to educate you.

```
// Get all the inputs to a ref object.
render() {
   var indents = [];
   for (var i = 1; i <= this.state.box; i++){
    indents.push(<Input ref={(input) => this[`input_${i}`] = input;} fluid label={i} placeholder='Item Description..' style={{padding: 5}} />);
   }
}
```

Then assume you have a `onSubmit` method to get all the values. Fetch the value like this

```
onSubmit = () => {
  const values = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= this.state.box; i++){
   values.push(this[`input_${i}`].value);
  }
 // now your `values` variable will have all the values
}
```

Comment: It gives me this error sir: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

Comment: Did you render those indents on to the ui ? When are you calling the onsubmit method ?

Comment: yes I did what you say but it gives me an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when I click submit button, so I think there's something to do with the listener.